# Dynamic speed of vehicles in PDP scenario

Tags: java, rinsim

Is there a way to provide dynamic speed to vehicles (e.g. dependent on the vehicle payload)?

The `VehicleDTO` class is immutable and not extensible, yet is required in the `PDPModel` base class and all its subclasses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to extend `VehicleDTO` you can do so via composition (as you shouldn't inherit from value objects):

```
@AutoValue
abstract class MyVehicleDTO {
  public abstract VehicleDTO getVehicleDto();

  // add more properties
}
```

The example above uses [AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto/blob/master/value/userguide/index.md) to create a value object, but that's not required. You can use this value object to define your custom vehicle as follows:

```
public class MyVehicle extends Vehicle {
  public MyVehicle(MyVehicleDTO vehicleDto) {
    super(vehicleDto.getVehicleDto());
  }

  @Override
  public double getSpeed() {
    // change the following line to have a dynamic speed
    return dto.getSpeed();
  }

  @Override
  protected void tickImpl(TimeLapse time) {}
}
```

By creating your own `Vehicle` you can change the speed dynamically.

**Note**: make sure you are using RinSim v4.4.4 (or later) to be able to override the speed.